I can't draw on the blender model
I recently started to use Blender to make models for my Roblox game. I began by simply using Blender with the idea of making some armor. Unfortunately, the draw tool stopped working after I used some tools such as the box trim and scale. I start by using the trim tool to make flat edges most of the time but even when it works, I can no longer edit that object without using Dyntopo. Even with Dyntopo on though (Dyntopo is on 2p), it still produces very odd results such as one side being indented while the other side is perfectly fine (basically meaning it's flat or the result is how I want it). Another problem with it being on is the drawn results having holes or the pieces not connecting with one another. It's happened to me a lot of times and I just keep deleting the projects and creating new ones in hope that the error doesn't pop up again but well, it does. I have no idea how to fix this and Youtube videos and websites didn't help me at all. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?



We need much more information such as images and/or a Blend file which is showing the problem. Also, what is a "box trim tool"?
